# How to take checkpoints in a program?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The idea of checkpointing is that at a particular moment of time when a program is running, a snapshot of the program's **state** is taken and stored in storage. Later, if the program experiences a failure, it rolls back to its most recent checkpoint and resumes execution from there. For example, we have a Fibonacci code as follows:

```
num0, num1 = 0, 1
c = 0
print(num0)
print(num1)
while c<20:
    num = num0 + num1
    print(num)
    num0, num1 = num1, num
    c += 1
```

And we want to take checkpoint after `print(num)`:

```
num0, num1 = 0, 1
c = 0
print(num0)
print(num1)
while c<20:
    num = num0 + num1
    print(num)

    # take a checkpoint here

    num0, num1 = num1, num
    c += 1
```

During the execution of the program, let's assume the code has printed out `0 1 1 2 3 5` and the last checkpoint has been taken. We terminate the program and then resume it from the most recent checkpoint taken. It should then start printing out from `8 13 21` to the end. My question is how to obtain the in-memory data structure of a program to save it to storage to have a checkpoint? My OS is ubuntu 22.04. The above code was just an example to make the idea of checkpointing clear.

Comment: Python's [`pickle` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) is made to do what you want.  If you apply it to a class object or a module it should capture everything you need.

Comment: OOP is ideal for this: you can capture the state of an object, serialize it to a file, restore the object, and keep processing with its state. If you design the object and its methods well such that a snapshot can be taken at any time and its methods can continue work at any point, this is fairly simple.